# Any tips on context manager similar to Python in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I quite liked Python's context manager where I did not have to be concerned with how the resource was obtained or cleaned up afterwards. Is there a way to do this in a neat way in Javascript?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make something similar using generator functions in javascript:

```js
function* usingGroup() {
   // setup
   console.group()
   try {
     yield
   } finally {
     // cleanup
     console.groupEnd()
   }
}
```

and to use it, you can use a `for ... of` loop:

```js
for(const _ of usingGroup()) {
   console.log('inside a group')
}
```

This method is similar to how you define context managers in python using the `@contextmanager` decorator. Although the way of using a for loop to define where the context applies feels strange in my opinion.

*How does it work:*

Abstracting away the whole generator object and iterator protocol, you can think of it as doing this: before the first iteration of the loop, the code inside the generator function is run until the `yield` statement, at this point, the for loop body runs once since a value has been yielded by the generator, before the next iteration, the rest of the code in the generator is run. Since it does not yield, the loop considers it done and exits without executing its body again. The `try ... finally` ensures that even if an error is thrown, the code gets executed.

If you need to use some value inside your loop (like a file you opened for example), you can just `yield` it inside the generator.

*full code:*

```js
function* usingGroup() {
   console.group()
   try {
     yield
   } finally {
     console.groupEnd()
   }
}

for(const _ of usingGroup()) {
   console.log('inside a group')
}
```

EDIT:
Since this answer seems to have some attention, I feel it is important to address a couple of issues with it.

First this trick might be unfamiliar to most and most likely will result in code that is confusing to most, I'd say it isn't a good code style. To alleviate that, you can use a callback-based method to make what is happening more explicit.

The other issue this has is that in its state, nothing prevents, verifies, or can verify really, that the generator only yields once, if at all. This implies some fragility and that you cannot really be certain the for loop body executes only once. This is fixable at runtime by wrapping/decorating the context managing generator function.

Lastly, this answer will become obsolete in the coming years when the [explicit resource management proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-explicit-resource-management) will be accepted into stage 4.

Answer (score 8):

I'm happy to break this to you, we now have that in JavaScript. It's a tiny library called "contextlib" (closely resembling python's contexlib).

Disclaimer: I authored contextlib.

You can install using `npm install contextlib`.

```js
import {With, contextmanager} from 'contextlib';

class context:
    enter() { console.log('entering context') }

    exit() { console.log('leaving context') }

With(new context(), () => {
   console.log('inside context')
})
```

You can also use the `contextmanager` decorator

```
context = contextmanager(function*(){
    try {
        console.log('entering context')
        yield
    } finally {
        console.log('leaving context')
    }
})
```

You should check it out on [github](https://github.com/mcsavvy/contextlib).

Comment: Super neat. Wanted to create an http server for an auth flow and throw it away after and thought to myself that context managers in Python would do that for me. Was surprised to see it didn't exist in JS somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunately contextlib's distribution is broken. This looked really promising! May fork, PR, & republish.

Answer (score 3):

I also surprised by missing this feature. Unfortunately, only callback based solutions are available in JS

https://promise-nuggets.github.io/articles/21-context-managers-transactions.html