# Mongoose DocumentDB too many cursors

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, mongoose, aws-documentdb

I have a simple RestAPI utilizing Express.js Typescript and Mongoose running on AWS together with DocumentDB cluster. Once in a while I get an error stating that I have too many cursors open (10) and the database just doesn't accept any more read operations. Is there a way in mongoose to close cursors after querying the database?

Answer (score 0):

Python provides a very neat way to manage the database connections inside Context Managers. npm has a similar implementation - `contextlib` - to manage the setup and teardown process. A similar question was answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/71383627/19810639